# random maass waveforms

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems

Let $H$ be the upper half complex plane and $\Gamma$ a discrete subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that the volume of of $\Gamma \backslash H$ is finite. There is a conjecture of Berry that Maass waveforms on $\Gamma \backslash H$ behave like random waves as the frequency (or eigenvalue) of the waveform tends to $\infty$. My question is, why is this conjecture made? I'm not a physicist so please explain slowly.

Comment: A naive comment: There might be (I guess there is) some connection of Berry conjecture with Quantum unique ergodicity for $\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak{H}$, finite volume case.